# C# program without UI

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a Visual C# program that runs without a console or windows form? If so, how?

Comment: Would a Windows service or website be options?

Comment: Not a website, but a I will look into a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also create a Windows Service app; start and stop the app via the Services Management console.

Comment: This looks to be the best option. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Sure- set the build output type to Windows Application under Project Properties, and don't show a form in Main. You can do whatever you want in there- you just have to manage the lifetime of the app somehow (eg, how do you plan to shut it down?)

Comment: I tried making a new instance of a formless class in the Main. But I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'test.runTime' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext'". I needs a Form to start with if the output type is Windows Application under Project Properties.